# How long does it take for the Club to appear?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Dr Shrunk showed up 4 days ago and had me gather petitions for a new club. I got the signatures and he said they'd be working on it. But several days later there's no Club LOL and no apparent indication of any work being done.

Is there anything I have to do to make the club appear or am I done? When will it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you get all the petition signatures, it takes 5 days for the club to appear. So you just have to be patient!

Comment: I have to wonder, did this necessitate a full Q&A, or could it have been answered in chat?

Comment: It's a question, I had an answer. Boom, a reason to post, no? The size of the answer shouldn't matter.